# How do I add values that are in a python list without having to do it manually

Tags: python, list, addition

How do i a values in a list.

Like lets say i have 5 numbers 1, 2, 6, 23, 5 and i want to store their total inside a variable without having to do it manually.

Because i will make the program let the user input their own values and i cant guess the values.

this is what i got when i searched it up

```
l = list(range(3))
l.append([3, 4, 5])
print(l)
# [0, 1, 2, 100, 'new', [3, 4, 5]]
```

[Source of code above](https://note.nkmk.me/en/python-list-append-extend-insert/)

Comment: Have you tried anything? I'm not seeing where you are taking user input, nor where you are taking a sum

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to allow users to input things to the list, you can try

```
for i in range(num):
    list.append(int(input('Enter a number: ')))
```

where `num` is how many inputs you want

and then you can use Python `sum()` function to find the sum:

`total = sum(list)`

Answer (score 0):

Simple way:

```
total = sum(myList)
```

Answer (score -1):

What you need to do is to loop through all the numbers and calculate the total.

```
myList = [1, 2, 6, 23, 5]

total = 0

for number in myList:
    total = total + number

print(total)
```

Output

```
37
```

**Alternative Method**

```
myList = [1, 2, 6, 23, 5]
total = sum(myList)
print(total)
```

Output

```
37
```

I hope this answer's your question! If you need any clarifications just feel free to comment below ^-^ I'm here to help!

Comment: Or use the built-in `sum` function that you just partially reinvented.

Comment: @chepner Thanks! I've updated my answer to include your suggestion.

Comment: Thank you it work